# Why do these two methods of sampling primes run equally long?

Tags: java, random, clojure, primes

So I've implemented my own little RSA algorithm and in the course of that I wrote a function to find large prime numbers.
First I wrote a function `prime?` that tests for primality and then I wrote two versions of a prime searching function. In the first version I just test random BigIntegers until I hit a prime. In the second version I sample a random BigInteger and then incremented it until I find a prime.

```
(defn resampling []
  (let [rnd (Random.)]
    (->> (repeatedly #(BigInteger. 512 rnd))
         (take-while (comp not prime?))
         (count))))

(defn incrementing []
  (->> (BigInteger. 512 (Random.))
       (iterate inc)
       (take-while (comp not prime?))
       (count)))

(let [n 100]
  {:resampling   (/ (reduce + (repeatedly n resampling)) n)
   :incrementing (/ (reduce + (repeatedly n incrementing)) n)})
```

Running this code yielded the two averages of 332.41 for the resampling function and 310.74 for the incrementing function.
Now the first number makes complete sense to me. The [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem%22prime%20number%20theorem%22) states that the `n`'th prime is about `n*ln(n)` in size (where `ln` is the natural logarithm). So the distance between adjacent primes is approximately `n*ln(n) - (n-1)*ln(n-1) ≈ (n - (n - 1))*ln(n) = ln(n)` (For large values of `n` `ln(n) ≈ ln(n - 1)`). Since I'm sampling 512-bit integers I'd expect the distance between primes to be in the vicinity of `ln(2^512) = 354.89`. Therefore random sampling should take about 354.89 attempts on average before hitting a prime, which comes out quite nicely.
The puzzle for me is why the incrementing function is taking about just as many steps. If I imagine throwing a dart at a grid where primes are spaced 355 units apart, it should take only about half that many steps on average to walk to the next higher prime, since on average I'd be hitting the center between two primes.

(The code for `prime?` is a little lengthy. You can take a look at it [here](https://github.com/SOberhoff/tnoc/blob/master/src/tnoc/rsa.clj).)

Comment: Maybe because half of the numbers you are testing with the increment method are even?

Comment: @rossum same for the `resampling` method, so I don't think that is the reason

Comment: Checking it I got a similar number. My Math is quite rusty and it was never that good to begin with but from what I can understand the distribution of prime numbers is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution which means that those numbers make sense from here: http://phillipmfeldman.org/mathematics/primes.html "The sum of any two independent Poisson random variables yields another Poisson random variable." this question is probably much better suited in cs or one of the math sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assume that primes are equally distributed, that seems not to be the case.

Let's consider the following possible scenario: If primes would always come as pairs for example `10...01` and `10...03` then the next pair would come in `2*ln(n)`. For the sampling algorithm this distribution makes no difference, but for the incrementing algorithm the probability to start inside of a such pair is almost 0, so this means it would need to go a half of the big distance on average, that is `ln(n)`.

In a nutshell: to estimate the behavior of the incremental algorithm right, it is not enough to know the average distance between the primes.

Comment: Of course! I just realized the same mistake when I woke up. So if I idealize the primes as being Poisson distributed with `λ = 1/355` then when I make an initial sample the wait time until the next prime will be exponentially distributed with the same `λ`. And the expected value of an exponentially distributed random variable is `1/λ = 355`. I should've seen this way sooner.

Comment: @SebastianOberhoff Nice explanation, much cleaner than my hand-waving argument!